# google play service location error Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

When I update my play-services-location to 11.0.2 I get following error.

```
package com.google.android.gms.maps does not exist
package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not exist
```

When play-services-location was 9.0.1 it works fine. I need to integrate this app into another app where dependencies are :

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

When I tried to set all to 9.0.1, I get following error:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:9.0.1'
```

Error:Failed to resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:9.0.1

Do I need to update Google play services. Please help.

Comment: None of those are `play-services-maps`... Why would you use `9.0.2` with `11.0.2`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
```

By the way, [latest version](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) is `11.4.2`

Comment: Please see the latest edited question. I've included them. Still got error. On 1st app of map, only when I set it to 9.0.1 it works fine. When I set to 11.0.2, it shows error.

Comment: All dependencies need to be the same version

Comment: And you have `location`, not `maps`

Comment: Yes. At last part of question. I've made all to same.                                   
   Still error Error:Failed to resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:9.0.1

Comment: I'm not even sure appindexing `9.0.1` exists. See documentation here. As stated, latest version is 11.4.2 https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/app